# How to set TargetType to this in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom `UserControl` (e.g. called *MyUserControl*) with several child controls. I would like to create a `UserControl.Resources` with set of styles and dependency properties assignments for design purposes (without styles the control looks like a ball of mud). Later I will comment that styles.

The problem is, that I don't know how to set `TargetType` of style in order to point out the `UserControl` that is being developed.

Here is an example how it could look like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="this">
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourProjectName.UserControl1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectName"

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl>
```